# fluent nhibernate relationships mapping

Tags: c#

I'm having a hard time understanding how to define relationships between different classes(tables) using fluent nhibernate.

Here are my thoughts :

> One to one relationhip example:

```
class Employee {
    public virtual int idEmployee;
    public virtual string name;
    public virtual int idState;

    public virtual State currentState;
}

class State {
   public virtual int idState;
   public virtual int label;

   public virtual Employee emp;
}
```

An Employee can have one state.An state can be attached to only one employee.

- Employee contains the reference(fk->object type) to the state he has.
- State contains the referece(fk->object type) of the current employee.

***(Foreign key(idState) REFERENCES State(idState))***

/-----------------------------------/

> One to many relationship example:

```
    class Employee {
        public virtual int idEmployee;
        public virtual string name;

        public virtual List<State> currentStates;
    }

   class State {
       public virtual int idState;
       public virtual int idEmployee;
       public virtual int label;

       public virtual Employee emp;}
```

An employee can have multiple states(contains list of references to all states).A state can be attached to an employee.(state contains reference to its employee)

- The employee contains the list with all the object references he has
  to the state
- The state contains the refernce to its employee.

**(Foreign key(idEmployee) References State(idEmployee))**

/-----------------------------------/

> Many to many :

```
  class Employee {
        public virtual int idEmployee;
        public virtual string name; }

   class JobTypes {
       public virtual int idJobType;
       public virtual string label;}

  class Tasks{ 
     public virtual int idTask;
     public virtual int idEmployee;
     public virtual int idJobType;
     public virtual DateTime dateStart;
     public virtual DateTime dateEnd;

     public virtual Employee emp;
     public virtual JobTypes jt;}
```

a)Should I still add the primitive key type in each corresponding class?
b)Does the parent should know about its child?
c)Am I right with what I've been writing about the relationships?